# Undefined variable for hidden input after registration - Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, authentication

I have this method of trying to get their email to resend verification link if they didnt receive the first time. The problem is i dont want to let them login without verification because this database is connected with a game server and i dont want them to log in without verification. I tried to store the email so the resend button resends it to that email the verification link but after i register and when its trying to redirect me to the verify.blade i get.

> Undefinded variable: user

And its pointing to the hidden input which i will show below.

**This is my registration function which works fine and registers the user in the database:**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = Account::create([
            'login' => $data['login'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'verifyToken'=> Str::random(40),
            'active' => (env('CONFIRM_EMAIL', true)) ? 0 : 1
        ]);
        $thisUser = Account::findOrFail($user->id);

        if(env('CONFIRM_EMAIL') == true){
            $this->sendEmail($thisUser);
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

**This is the function that redirects or logins the user depending if i have set to True the email verification:**

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        if(env('CONFIRM_EMAIL') == false){
            $this->guard()->login($user);
        }else{
            return redirect(route('verifyEmail'));
        }

        if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new Response('', 201)
            : redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

**and this is the resend function and html code with the hidden input that points the error to the value="$user->email":**

```
protected function resend(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Account::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if($user){
            $user->verifyToken = Str::random(40);
            $user->save();
            $this->sendEmail($user);
            return back()->with('user',$user)->with('success', 'A link has been sent to your email');
        }
    }
```

```
<form action=" {!! route('resendEmail') !!}" method="POST">
    @csrf

    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}">
    <button class="btn btn-default db" type="submit" value="Submit">Resend Verification Link</button>
</form>
```

**This is the route for verifyemail which i dont know how to pass the email parameter:**

```
 return redirect(route('verifyEmail'));
```

Comment: change this line `value="{{ $user->email }}` to `value="{{ $user->email ?? null  }}` I think on your get method, you hav not defined `user` variable. If you post the route, then its will be better to understand

Comment: What route would you like me to post? @STA

Comment: which is belongs to `resend` function, post both post and get method

Comment: `Route::post('/resend/email', 'Auth\RegisterController@resend')->name('resendEmail');` i only have a post for this resend

Comment: I think this page has a `get` method too.

Comment: `Route::get('/verify', 'Auth\RegisterController@verifyEmail')->name('verifyEmail');` This is the redirection to verify blade after registration

Comment: You need to send the email to the page: `redirect(route('verifyEmail'))->with( [ 'email' => $user->email ] );`. And then, you need to read the email from the session: `session()->get( 'email' ) ` not from `$user->emai`. If it works, I`ll post as a answer.

Comment: >Trying to get property 'email' of non-object< do i need to create $user before sending the email to the verify page? i have it like this: $user = Account::where('email', $request->email)->first();
            return redirect(route('verifyEmail'))->with( [ 'email' => $user->email ] ); and in the hidden input: <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ session()->get( 'email' )}}">.